# Picking a Shard Key on an Generic Collection

Tags: mongodb

Let's say my collection's structure looks like:

```
{ 
   _id = ObjectId(1),
   records : [ {n: "Name", v: "Kevin"}, 
               ...,  
               {n: "Age", v: 100} 
             ]
}
```

Since I have a single compound index (`records.n-records.v`), would that be my shard key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`records` is an array and you [cannot use multi-key index for shard key](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-multikey/#shard-keys) so the answer is no, you cannot use it as a shard key.

I would say that schema like this is generally speaking rather useless - it is hard to query, hard to modify don't even mention sorting. Subdocument with records `{"Name": "Kevin", "Age": 100}` would be a better choice, and you could use some subset of fields as a shard key.

Comment: Could I create a shard key with my collection & single index then?

Comment: Personally I would choose different schema (see edited answer for details).

Comment: I appreciate the suggested schema update. However, I need to keep the generic n-v structure due to my heavy indexing requirements.

Comment: If `_id` using `ObjectId` and array of `records` is all you have in the documents there is no way to create useful shard key. Using single field from `records` (`n` or `v`) changes nothing and `ObjectId`s are poor shard keys. You could use custom field for `_id` but it means you'll have to use it in the queries to make use of sharding.